# How do I set the input context in c# for dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

This is what I am currently trying to do but I just dont see how to add the input context in

Thanks

Steve

```
                var client = Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.SessionsClient.Create();
                var Session = new Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.SessionName(DialogflowProject, communicationId);


                var commonContext = new global::Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.Context
                {
                    ContextName = new ContextName(DialogflowProject, Session.SessionId, communicationId),
                    LifespanCount = 1
                };
                
               
                var response = client.DetectIntent(
                        session: Session,
                        queryInput: new QueryInput()
                        {
                            Text = new TextInput()
                            {
                                Text = question,
                                LanguageCode = "en"
                            }
                        }
                    );

                answer = response.QueryResult.FulfillmentText.ToString();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more about what you would like to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: hi, Sure.  depending on who is asking the chatbot a question will determine the potential answer they get.  I have set up the intents with different input contexts within the console and when they ask the question I have their Id (which is the input context on their relevant intents).  What I dont seem to be able to do though is set the context programmatically so when it gets to the intents its there.

Comment: I would like to share official documentations: [1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-csharp), [2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/csharp). There is a very good example provided.